# Jsonpath: How do you find a node by a child node's value?

Tags: jsonpath

```
"things":[
  ...
  {
    "id":10,
    "stuff":"words"
  }
]
```

Let's say I don't know what index that object is at, but I do know that the id = 10. Is there a way to find it using JSONpath?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@ = currentObject
?() = filter

things.*[?(@.id=10)].stuff
```

source: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: This answer helped me on a similar problem, but I'm pretty sure that your id=10 statement should actually be a double equals ( i.e.  things.*[?(@.id==10)].stuff  )

Comment: I've found that the double equals is needed, while the ".*" is not. This expression is what works for me: things[?(@.id==10)].stuff